# New form in hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, list-form

I am creating a hosted app in Visual Studio 2017 for use in SharePoint 2016 On-Premises.  I have added a list to this project and would like to change the new item form for this list.  I am attempting to follow [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wilsonreddygajarla/2014/12/13/sharepoint-list-newform-customization-in-sharepoint-hosted-app/) tutorial, but when I select Add -> New Item, I don't have any item called Page.  Is this something I'm missing or is there a different way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`.aspx page` include in your sharepoint add in

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why, but I don't have that.

Comment: Add `Application page` it work same.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Utkarsh Dubey, Application Page works, but only with some changes.  In the aspx page, DynameMasterPageFile has to be changed to MasterPageFile and in the code behind, you have to inherit from WebPartPage rather than LayoutsPageBase.